# Fluent NHibernate inheritance mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, inheritance, fluent-nhibernate, single-table-inheritance

In my hierarchy of animals

**Base one:**

```
public class AnimalMap : ClassMap<Animal>
{
    public AnimalMap()
    {
      Schema("dbo");
      Table("Animals");   

      Id(x => x.Id).Column("ID").GeneratedBy.Identity();
      Map(x => x.FoodClassification).Column("FoodClassification");
      Map(x => x.BirthDate).Column("BirthDate");
      Map(x => x.Family).Column("Family");

      DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("ClassType").Not.Nullable();    
    }
}
```

**One subclass:**

```
public class DogMap : SubclassMap<Dog>
{
    public DogMap()
    {
          DiscriminatorValue(@"Dog");
          Map(x => x.Field).Column("Field");
    }
}
```

So the question is:

Where column "ClassType" != Dog , **Animal** should be object type, like base one. Each one who has no mapping class should have base(super) one.

How to make it works?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, if you had a class of type `Giraffe : Animal`, how would the column value be persisted if you never specified a discriminator value for giraffe.

Comment: but what should to do if i don't need classification for everyone who is not a dog? i mean each?, even giraffe, should be an animal but not a giraffe

Comment: What would the discriminator value be for the other types?

Comment: some other word like 'animal' but not dog... or null or empty string. whatever, but they should be Animal class type

Comment: Try to make a common abstract base type (like `BaseAnimal`), and have both `Animal` and `Dog` derive from it.  Then you would set-up 2 subclass mappings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

important: only do this to support legacy schemas and animal is readonly

```
public class SomeAnimal : Animal
{

}

public class AnimalMap : ClassMap<Animal>
{
    public AnimalMap()
    {
      Schema("dbo");
      Table("Animals");   

      Id(x => x.Id).Column("ID").GeneratedBy.Identity();
      Map(x => x.FoodClassification).Column("FoodClassification");
      Map(x => x.BirthDate).Column("BirthDate");
      Map(x => x.Family).Column("Family");

      DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn().Formula("IIF(classtype = 'dog', 'dog', 'someAnimal')");
    }
}

public class SomeAnimalMap : SubclassMap<SomeAnimal>
{
    public SomeAnimalMap()
    {
          ReadOnly();

          DiscriminatorValue("someAnimal");
          Map(x => x.ClassType).Column("classtype");
    }
}
```

Comment: see the solution, but question is how to avoid this one?

Comment: Avoid specifying all subclass values in the Formula or the additional class SomeAnimal?

Comment: additional class SomeAnimal

Comment: you can with `DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("", "someAnimal").Formula(...);`